# Ionic 3 - npm i Running Command Failed

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3

Recently I was interested in Ionic, so I followed the getting started guide from the website and other tutorials on the topic.

- I got node installed.
- everything is ok to the installation of Cordova and Ionic.

But every time I try to create a simple app (any template)
I got the same exact error:

```
C:\Users\[myuser]\IonicProjects>ionic start demo1 blank

√ Creating directory .\demo1 - done!
Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-
base/archive/master.tar.gz)
√ Downloading - done!
Fetching starter template blank (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-blank/archive/master.tar.gz)
√ Downloading - done!
√ Updating package.json with app details - done!
√ Creating configuration file ionic.config.json - done!
Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

> npm i
× Running command - failed!
Error
    at new Exception (C:\Users\[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\errors.js:8:23)
    at new ShellException (C:\Users\[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\errors.js:26:9)
    at ChildProcess.p.on.code (C:\Users\[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\utils\shell.js:68:28)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\WINDOWS 10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

I have to run the same "ionic start ..." over and over like 5-10 times just to create the project without any error messages.

The error message doesn't appear to give more information on what is wrong.

Is there a missing step or something, or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Running command failed Ionic:

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic

npm cache clean -f

sudo npm install -g cordova@6.5.0
```

In the above steps you can follow exactly working. Enjoy your coding.